# How to use "IN" command properly with JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm having some problens on using the commando "IN" on my jpql, here's the case:
I have these classes:

```
public class Empresa{

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_empresa")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private TipoEmpresa tipoEmpresa;
}

public class TipoEmpresa{
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long valor;
}
```

Then I have this service, that sends a List of "TipoEmpresa" to my EmpresaRepository's query:

SERVICE

```
public List<Empresa> getEmpresasByTipoEmpresaAndTipoStatus(List<TipoEmpresa>tiposEmpresa) {
    List<Empresa> listaDeEmpresas=empresaRepository.getEmpresasByTipoEmpresa(tiposEmpresa);
    return listaDeEmpresas;
}
```

REPOSITORY

```
@Query(name = "SELECT E FROM Empresa E WHERE E.tipoEmpresa IN(:tipoEmpresa)")
List<Empresa> getEmpresasByTipoEmpresaAndTipoStatus(@Param("tipoEmpresa") List<TipoEmpresa> tipoEmpresa);
```

As you can see I'm trying to get all "Empresa" that have a "tipoEmpresa" listed on my List, but when colling the service I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I don't know what to do anymore, tried everything I could think of, what am I doing wrong ?

hi Dude ! first things first, thanks for helping !

.
.
.

I tried g.Irani's suggestion, changed my code, that got like this:

Repository

```
@Query(name = "SELECT E FROM Empresa E WHERE E.tipoEmpresa.id  IN :tipoEmpresa ")
List<Empresa> getEmpresasByTipoEmpresaAndTipoStatus(@Param("tipoEmpresa") List<Long> tipoEmpresa);
```

Service

```
//just a test...
List<Long> test =Arrays.asList(100l, 200l);
List<Empresa> listaDeEmpresas=empresaRepository.getEmpresasByTipoEmpresa(test);
```

But now I got this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [100] did not match expected type [br.com.entities.TipoEmpresa (n/a)]
```

Any thoughts about it ?

Answer (score 0):

after IN in WHERE clause, you should present a list with 1 column. 
tipoEmpresa in below query of your code is a class (with 2 columns) 
**@Query(name = "SELECT E FROM Empresa E WHERE E.tipoEmpresa IN(:tipoEmpresa)")**

you can use 
@Query(name = "SELECT E FROM Empresa E WHERE **E.tipoEmpresa.id** IN(:tipoEmpresaIDs)") 

then prepare a list of tipoEmpresa IDs and set to :tipoEmpresaIDs 
 
notice that, In JPA when using IN, you don't need ( ) after IN. (just use ... **IN :tipoEmpresaIDs**)

Comment: Hi Dude, thanks for helping, but now I'm getting another error message, I edited my question with it, do you have any ideas aboute it ?